# Numpy dot product of very large arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem of very slow running code. A try to calculate the dot product of a very large binary matrix  (170544 X 22) by its transpose. 
First I tried this code

```
import numpy as np
start = time.time()
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message='genfromtxt',     category=UserWarning)
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)

fin = open('E:/myscripts/Abin.txt', 'rb')    # input file (170544X22     binary matrix)
fin1 = open('E:/myscripts/AbinT.txt', 'rb')    # input file (22X170544        binary matrix the transpose of Abin)
fout = open('E:/myscripts/RPartial.txt', 'w+b')  # output file

FW = np.genfromtxt(fin,delimiter=',',   dtype=int)
WF = np.genfromtxt(fin1,delimiter=',',   dtype=int)

r = np.dot(FW,WF) #r calculation
np.savetxt(fout, r,  fmt='%i' ,delimiter=',', newline='\r\n')

fin.close()
fin1.close()
fout.close()
```

but there was a memory error. Then I changed the r calculation using a row approach:

```
for row in FW:
    a=FW[row,:]
    r = np.dot(a,WF)
    np.savetxt(fout, r,  fmt='%i' ,delimiter=',', newline='\r\n')
```

The code now works, but its is very  slow, after 90 min only 8000 rows was calculated. 
The hardware is a I7 with 12GB of ram, running windows 64 bits.
How a can speed up the code?

The data is like this

```
([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0])
```

and the result should be like

```
([15,14,14,14,14],
 [14,15,14,14,14],
 [14,14,15,14,14],
 [14,14,14,15,14],
 [14,14,14,14,15]) .
```

Comment: Calculating the result with your row approach takes 460s (int) or 129s (float32). Your real problem is the data IO. Why do you use text files for saving and loading your data? When working with somewhat bigger data this should be absolutely avoided...(very slow, very big files)

Comment: Your output will be about 232 GB in size (dense matrix, uncompressed int64). Please add also what you wan't to do with the data afterwards...

Comment: I tried save the data as npy files. Again return the memory error . After this calculation i will summarize the results by row.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) problem for which scipy provides a [package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). These are matrices with many 0 elements (like in your example). Operations will take the sparseness into account and the matrix will take up less space in memory. Remember to do matrix operations like `FW.dot(WF)` (use this rather than `np.dot`).

Comment: The sample does not have a high proportion of zeros.

Comment: Yes it does... some columns are all zero and in any case large blocks are zero. The scipy package can handle those.

Comment: Sparse matrices are useful when sparsity is on the order of 10% or less.

Comment: Sure, but extend that sample (I assume the top left of the matrix) right and down... what do you get? In any event, without the full data we don't know.

Comment: The lines of data has  40% to 50% of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

As I have written in the comments the output array will be 232GB in size(int64). If you wan't to store the results to disk using h5py for this task would be a proper solution.

A summation about first axis simplifies the problem a bit. If you wan't the pure dot product I can update my answer. But this will be a bit more complicated and slower.

```
res=np.zeros(WF.shape[1])
for i in range(WF.shape[1]):
  a=np.copy(WF[:,i])
  r=np.dot(FW,a)
  res[i] = np.sum(r)
```

Comment: Each element of dot product array is <15. And yes, I really need the dot product. Although the output array will be smaller than your prediction, its size suggests another approach to the problem, may be using a partitioned matrix.