# np.dot crash for big matrix because of memory overflow

Tags: numpy

I have a big matrix saved on a file representing the laplacian of a graph. The matrix is size 11548*11548. To load and have sparse matrix, I do

```
Lg = np.genfromtxt('./data/Breast_laplp2.csv', delimiter=',',skip_header=1)
Lg = csr_matrix(Lg)
```

I need to compute the dot product to a vector w, such as

```
np.dot(np.dot(w.T,Lg),w)
```

But this is failling because of memory issue (up to 128G). I don't understand why this is taking as much memories. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: The order of application might be incorrect, leading to the creation of a full dense matrix in the process.

Comment: Have you tried without using `csr_matrix(Lg)`? For sizes of 11548*11548 it should work fine.

Comment: Eventually take a look at  [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest)

Comment: Also this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686428/numpy-dot-product-of-very-large-arrays

Comment: I tested without csr_matrix and it worked. This is weird as I thought it was better using it?